# How add users to OpenVPN on Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: 16.04, users, openvpn, user-management

I have installed Open VPN using below command:

```
sudo wget git.io/vpn --no-check-certificate -O openvpn-install.sh && bash openvpn-install.sh
```

I have only one user.
How do I manage (add, remove) OpenVPN users?

Comment: https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/manuals.html

Comment: I asked to detail, you gave me a whole manuals :) Could you gibe me more compress data?

Answer (score 0):

Once OpenVPN installed, check from status about "Authenticate users with:" .If it shows "pam" then login to server and use command sudo adduser userid ,
Eg:
openvpnas@openvpnas2:~$ sudo adduser test1
Adding user `test1' ...
Adding new group`test1' (1007) ...
Adding new user `test1' (1007) with group`test1' ...
Creating home directory `/home/test1' ...
Copying files from`/etc/skel' ...
Enter new UNIX password:
Enter the password and it is added.You can confirm adding of user by using below comand:
sudo -su userid
Otherwise if status is local , then adding and deleting user can be managed from User permission in webUI.